# NLTK PoS tagging

Tags: python, nltk, tagging, part-of-speech

I'm new in Python and need it for PoS tagging. Therefore I tried to use the standard tools. I tried to create a tagger and get a ValueError, that I don't understand.
My code:

```
import nltk
tagged_sents = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(categories = 'reviews')
tagger =nltk.ClassifierBasedTagger(tagged_sents)
```

I have already checked, that tagged_sents is a list of all sentences. Each sentence self is a list of tuples (word, PoS), like in the documentation:

> :param train: A tagged corpus consisting of a list of tagged
>           sentences, where each sentence is a list of (word, tag) tuples.

Why do I get the Value Error?

> ValueError: Must specify either training data or trained model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed `tagged_sents` positionally, so it is being used as the `feature_detector` argument. You should construct the tagger like this:

```
tagger = nltk.ClassifierBasedTagger(train=tagged_sents)
```

See http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.sequential.ClassifierBasedTagger

Comment: It's also strange that `ClassifierBasedTagger` expects `feature_detector` in the first position though.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ptnplanet/NLTK-Contributions) works fine with your solution, although I did not see until now, when the ClassifierBasedTagger is called.

Comment: It might be better to train using `PerceptronTagger` http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/perceptron.html#PerceptronTagger.train.